# how to use session data in as variable in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel to put the session in my controller to store some items and to display it in a Blade view. While trying to `dd` that variable it returns true but showing nothing in it. This is my controller function:

```php
public function addToCompare(Request $request){
    $product= Product::find($request->id);
    $request->session()->put('key', $product);
    return $product->name;
}
```

This is my Blade view:

```php
@if(session()->get('key'))
<tr>
    <td><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
    @foreach(session()->get('key') as $products)
        <td><strong>{{$products->name}}</strong></td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

Comment: why are looping `session()->get('key')` you are assign single object when you do `Product::find` you can just go `session()->get('key')->name` for product name

Comment: Be careful when using dd in your controllers. Unless you call `session()->save()`, the session data is not persisted until the end of the request cycle.  dd will stop this.

Comment: Use laravel debugbar to see exactly what is in session